# Rearranging, looping, and matching elements in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML structure:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <globalRequesteeDepartment>
        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnOperations</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">JOB COST COORDNTR</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnOperations</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">ENGINEERING COORD</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnOperations</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">OPERATIONS COORDINAT</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnSafety</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">WC COORDINATOR</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnSafety</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">SAFETY DIRECTOR</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnSafety</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">SAFETY SPECIALIST IV</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnEquipment</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">EQUIP MANAGER</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnAccounting</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">CONTROLLER</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnAccounting</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">SR ACCOUNTANT</indexValue>
        </listItems>

        <listItems>
            <description type="varchar">HstnAccounting</description>
            <indexValue type="varchar">FINANCIAL ANALYST</indexValue>
        </listItems>

  </globalRequesteeDepartment>
```

It is possible to and how would I use XSLT to get the  following desired XML output:

```
<globalRequesteeDepartment>
    <HstnOperations>
        <indexValue>JOB COST COORDNTR</indexValue>
        <indexValue>ENGINEERING COORD</indexValue>
        <indexValue>OPERATIONS COORDINAT</indexValue>
    </HstnOperations>
    <HstnSafety>
        <indexValue>WC COORDINATOR</indexValue>
        <indexValue>SAFETY DIRECTOR</indexValue>
        <indexValue>SAFETY SPECIALIST IV</indexValue>
    </HstnSafety>
    <HstnEquipment>
        <indexValue>EQUIP MANAGER</indexValue>
    </HstnEquipment>
    <HstnAccounting>
        <indexValue>CONTROLLER</indexValue>
        <indexValue>SR ACCOUNTANT</indexValue>
        <indexValue>FINANCIAL ANALYST</indexValue>
    </HstnAccounting>
</globalRequesteeDepartment>
```

In summary:  every "listItems" has an "indexValue" tie to a "description".  I want to be able to have each "description" value to be its own element, but without the duplicate.  Then, the "indexValue" of each "listItems" should be a child element of matching "description" element.

Answer (score 0):

For this task use [`Muenchian grouping`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=muenchian+grouping).
So your XSLT can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- create a key to get all elements grouped -->
    <xsl:key name="distinct" match="listItems" use="description" />

    <xsl:template match="/globalRequesteeDepartment">
      <xsl:copy>
        <!-- apply to the first of each group with muenchian grouping-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="listItems[generate-id() = generate-id(key('distinct',description)[1])]" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="listItems">
      <xsl:element name="{description}">
        <!-- for-each over one whole group -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('distinct',description)">
          <indexValue><xsl:value-of select="indexValue"/></indexValue>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```